# Matching postcode to index of deprivation

Tags: r, match, converters, postal-code

I have a list of UK postcodes in my dataset, and I would like to convert them to their deprivation index. This website does it http://imd-by-postcode.opendatacommunities.org/imd/2019 but I need it to be done in R, rather than manually entering 1000s postcodes individually.

Does anyone have any experience/idea of a package that does this? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Office for National Statistics has some lookup tables that match postcodes to various scales of outputs areas, for example: [Postcode to Output Area](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/80628f9289574ba4b39a76ca7830b7e9_0)

Hopefully you can find a common field to merge by.

Answer (score 0):

A common field between the English postcodes and IMD can be done using the LSOA code. Details and code samples of linking can be found in this book by NHS-R Community https://health-inequalities.nhsrcommunity.com/content/imd.html